# Firebase Storage Verifying if an image exists and uploading it with a new name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
 uploadVariationImages(file, cb) {

    // nome do arquivo
    const fileName = file.name;
    // caminho para o storage
    const path = `abc/${fileName}`;
    let ref = this.afStorage.ref(path);
    console.log("First metadata: ", ref.getMetadata());
    ref.getMetadata().toPromise()
    .then( res => {
        let currentFileName = fileName.split(".")[0];
        let i = 1;
        let flag = true;
        do {
          let attempt = this.checkIfImageExists(i, currentFileName, file);
          attempt.toPromise()
          .then( (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            i++;
            console.log(i);
          })
          .catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(i);
            flag = false;
            console.log(i);
          })
        } while (flag === true)
      })
      .catch((error) => { // erro significa que nao achou metadata, ou seja, a imagem não existe.
        this.task = this.afStorage.upload(path, file);
        this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();
        console.log("1º: ", error);
        cb(error, null);
      });

  }

checkIfImageExists(file, cb) {

    // nome do arquivo
    const fileName = file.name;
    // caminho para o storage
    const path = `abc/${fileName}`;
    let ref = this.afStorage.ref(path);
    console.log("First metadata: ", ref.getMetadata());
    ref.getMetadata().toPromise()

  }
```

With this code i'm getting a forever loop, because it never enters the error(when it didn't find any image and it is meant to upload the image with a new number after the dash{-}). What i'm trying to do is upload an image but it has to verify its name first and if it already exists then it must insert an -1 after it or if that one already exists as well then insert and -2 and so on. For now, when it enters the second error i'm not uploading anything so that there i dont upload too many images if something happens, but if it would work I would have to insert the code to do that in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while (flag == true)` is not waiting for any promises to resolve, so this will go into a tight loop.

Recursion is typically your friend in situations like this:

```
function findFirstNonExistingFile(startAt, callback) {
  checkIfImageExits(startAt).then(() => {
    findFirstNonExistingFile(startAt+1, callback);
  }).catch(() => {
    callback(startAt);
  })
}
```

Since all calls are inside the promise results (`then` and `catch`), they always handle when the current file has been checked.

You'd use this with something like:

```
findFirstNonExistingFile(1, (i) => {
  console.log(i);
});
```

You can of course also implement this with a promise, but the flow would be the same.